# Поместить ключи словаря в список

Tags: python

помогите пожалуйста сделать следующий кусок кода более лаконичным

db здесь некоторый словарь

```
keys = []
for k in db:
    print(k, end = "\n")
    keys.append(k)
print(keys)
```

в итоге я получаю список из ключей словаря

Comment: Почитайте документацию к модулю shelve, почитайте про примитивы языка - списки, кортежи, массивы и таких подобных вопросов у Вас больше не возникнет  

    db.keys()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[db.keys()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys)

upd. на всякий случай - кроме [dict.keys()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) есть еще [dict.values()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) (список значений) и [dict.items()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) (список тюплов/кортежей ключ-значение), а также [dict.iterkeys()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iterkeys), [dict.itervalues()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) и [dict.iteritems()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems).